# Induction on record member in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Consider a simple example of induction on a record member:

```
Record Foo : Type := mkFoo { foo: nat }.

Definition double (f: Foo) : Foo :=
  mkFoo (2 * foo f)%nat.


Theorem double_doubles: forall (f: Foo),
    foo (double f) = (2 * foo f)%nat.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction (foo f).
  (* How do I prevent this loss of information? *)
  (* stuck? *)
Abort.


Theorem double_doubles: forall (f: Foo),
    foo (double f) = (2 * foo f)%nat.
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct f.
  (* destruct is horrible if your record is large / contains many things *)
  induction foo0.
  simpl. auto.
  intros. simpl. auto.
Qed.
```

At `induction (foo f)`, I am stuck with the goal
`foo (double f) = 2 * 0`.

I have somehow lost information that I am perform induction on `foo f` (I have no hypothesis stating that `foo f = 0`.

However, `destruct f` is unsatisfying, because I have ~5 member records that look very ugly in the hypothesis section when expanded out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Observe that `double_doubles` can be solved by `reflexivity` alone.

Comment: @indeed :) but I made the example simple for the sake of exposition. The actual problem is more complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `remember` tactic to give a name to an expression, yielding a variable that you can analyze inductively.  The tactic generates an equation connecting the variable to the remembered expression, allowing you to keep track of the information you need.

To illustrate, consider the following proof script.

```
Record Foo : Type := mkFoo { foo: nat }.

Definition double (f: Foo) : Foo :=
  mkFoo (2 * foo f)%nat.

Theorem double_doubles: forall (f: Foo),
    foo (double f) = (2 * foo f)%nat.
Proof.
  intros.
  remember (foo f) as n eqn:E.
  revert f E.
  induction n.
```

After calling `remember`, the goal becomes:

```
  f : Foo
  n : nat
  E : n = foo f
  ============================
  foo (double f) = 2 * n
```

If you do induction on `n` directly after `remember`, it is possible that you won't be able to complete your proof, because the induction hypothesis you will get will not be general enough.  If you run into this problem, you might need to generalize some of the variables that appear in the expression defining `n`. In the script above, the call `revert f E` puts `f` and `E` back into the goal, which solves this problem.

Comment: Thanks! is there a difference between "revert" and "generalize dependent"?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat `revert` will give you an error if you try to revert something that appears in the type of another term or hypothesis in the context. `generalize dependent` will compute all the terms whose types depend on the generalized one, and will put those back as well.

Comment: And between `revert dependent` and `generalize dependent` ?

Comment: @eponier Good question. I do not know.